# Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables in windows form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working in vb.net windows application.

In my load event I am giving code like this for loading data from different table to my datagridview.

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select M.Model,c.Colname,ma.Make from Model_tbl M join Color_tbl C on c.colid=M.mdlid join Make_tbl ma on ma.mkid=c.colid  where mdlid=5", con.connect)
        Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            DGV.DataSource = ds.Tables("MyTable")

        End If
```

While clicking update button I want to update data to different tables from my datagridview. So I given code like this in my update button.

```
 Me.Validate()
        Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables("MyTable"))
        Me.ds.AcceptChanges()
```

but in this line Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables("MyTable")) :

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

What changes I have to make in my code? If any one know how to resolve, please help me to find out.

Comment: See if adding the primary key to the original select statement helps.

Comment: sir,,what you mean? adding primary key to the original select statement ..

Comment: which table i have to add primary key?

Comment: A best practice is that most tables, especially those that will be updated, have primary keys (PK) defined. If all the tables invoked have PKs, and the JOIN is an equal join (exactly one record on each side always present) you have a chance that ADO.Net will generate the needed update SQL. Otherwise you may have to supply the proper SQL for an update. Or do the updates on your own and refresh the query results you are working with.

Comment: you need to make your own insert,update, and delete commands